# JQuery Sliding Div Jerks in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, slider

I am using the below test code to toggle a div based on a radio button selection.
The problem is when the div slides back up, there is an annoying jerk I notice
only in IE8. The same code works well in Firefox.

I tried changing the DOCTYPE to the one I am using in the test code below.

Could someone suggest how to eliminate the jerk / flicker in IE when the div slides up?

Below is the sample code I am testing with.

Thanks for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<style>
.div3{
width: 300px;
height:40px;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
.div4{
width: 300px;
height:80px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('[value="myDiv_3"]').attr('checked',true);
        $('.div3').show();

        $('input[name="myRadio"]').change(function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
            $('.div3').slideUp(3000);
            $('#'+selected).slideDown(3000);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>


<body style="text-align:center;">
<form action="example.com" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="myDiv_3" />MyDiv3
    <input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="myDiv_4" />MyDiv4
</form>
<div id="myDiv_3" class="div3">Div number 3!</div>
<div id="myDiv_4" class="div4">Div number 4!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will experience problems when working with Internet Explorer, that is the purpose of Internet Explorer after all.

Comment: Sample to watch the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/NUN76/ -- IE9 running fine in IE8 browser/document mode!?

Comment: Hi Smamatti: Thank you very much for posting this on jsfiddle. I haven't tried doing that. I am surprised that IE9 runs the same code without an issue in IE8 mode. But it doesn't work in IE8 browser.

Comment: IE9 in IE8-mode is **not** the same as IE8... it's still two different browser rendering engines.  The only way to fully test a browser version is to test within that browser version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a glitch because, when selecting the first radio button called `MyDiv3`, the following code tells the same `div` to slide up and down at the same time.

```
$('input[name="myRadio"]').change(function(){
     var selected = $(this).val();
     $('.div3').slideUp(3000);
     $('#'+selected).slideDown(3000);
});
```

Not exactly sure what your final effect is supposed to be and assuming the rest of the code is what you intended, you can try this...

```
$('input[name="myRadio"]').change(function(){
     var selected = $(this).val();
     if (selected === 'myDiv_3') {
         $('#myDiv_3').slideDown(3000);
     } else {
         $('#myDiv_3').slideUp(3000);
     }
});
```

[Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/wMfFe/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/wMfFe/2/)

---

**EDIT** after seeing [OP's demo page](http://markaz.x10.mx/IE8_Jerk_Fix.php):

In the page source...

```
<!-- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2263-Use-jQuery-s-SlideDown-With-Fixed-Width-Elements-To-Prevent-Jumping.htm -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
```

The OP's demo page is slipping IE8 into `quirks-mode` because the `doctype` is not the very first line in the file.  [The `doctype` must always come first](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html).  Using the tools at F12 verifies active `quirks-mode`, and then forcing `IE8 Standards Mode` fixes the jerky animation issue.

Removing everything above `doctype` including the empty space will prevent IE8 from slipping into `quirks-mode` as long as the rest of the page is also properly [validated](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://markaz.x10.mx/IE8_Jerk_Fix.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: Thanks for your response!! I tried your code but it did not produce the effect I am trying to achieve.
This is the behavior I am trying to accomplish:
When the page loads, the radio button MyDiv3 is shown selected. Both the divs - Div3 and Div4 are shown expanded. This is the default.

When user clicks on radio button MyDiv4, Div3 slides up. When user 
clicks back on button MyDiv3, Div3 slides down. In other words
clicking on radio buttons alternatively causes Div3 to slide up
or down.

Comment: @user765081, I edited my answer.  It should now produce the effect as you just described.

Comment: Hi Sparky672, thank you very much for your response. I replaced the code with your edited answer. I still notice the jerk with IE8 browser when Div3 slides up. Surprisingly, when I opened the jsfiddle link in IE8 and tried your solution, I dont see the problem!. Could it be that I am not using the right DOCTYPE, or perhaps there is a patch to the IE8 browser that I might be missing. The version says 8.0.60001.18702

Comment: @user765081, I cannot see your page so I can't even begin to guess what the problem may be.  Does it [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?  I use the following without problems.  `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

Comment: @user765081,  It may also depend on the actual content of the `div`.  Does it contain HTML?  Are you giving it borders, margins or padding?  Try plain text without margins, borders or padding just to see if the jerking is still there.  Since the jsFiddle is working for you in IE8, your page should too.

Comment: Hi Sparky672, thanks for replying back! At the moment I am only trying the test code - in fact, the exact same code as the working one in jsfiddle. No margins, padding, but only the 1 px border I have for the Divs. Thanks.

Comment: @user765081, That's the way to do it then... just the most basic page to start with.

Comment: sorry, if I did not make myself clear. It still does not work in IE8 browser. Would you get a chance to test it? Thank for your help!

Comment: @user765081, without your URL, there is nothing for anyone to test.  The jsFiddle is working perfectly here.

Comment: ,Thank you. Here is the URL --> http://markaz.x10.mx/IE8_Jerk_Fix.php
Please try this link in IE8 and let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: @user765081, Yes, I see the jerk in IE8, but not in the jsFiddle. You have a comment above your [`doctype`](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html). You **cannot** have _anything_ above `doctype` or IE will go into quirks mode. Not even a line-break... `doctype` **must** be the first thing in the file. You also must not have read my previous comment where I asked you if your site was [validated](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmarkaz.x10.mx%2FIE8_Jerk_Fix.php&charset=%28daetect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: thank you. It now works like a charm with IE8. Learnt one new thing about the DOCTYPE. Accepted your answer. Thank you again. You made my day!!